# Load moments with url and type, network error

Tags: android, google-api, google-plus

For my android app, I am trying to search for the app activities, previously created by the user, by specifying the activity url and type.

To be clear, this code works :

```
GoogleApiClient mga = contexte.getApiClient();
if (mga != null && mga.isConnected()) {
    Plus.MomentsApi.load(mga, NB_MOMENTS, null, null, null, "me").setResultCallback(this);
}
```

but the following code, fails with a "NETWORK_ERROR" status :

```
GoogleApiClient mga = contexte.getApiClient();
if (mga != null && mga.isConnected()) {
    Plus.MomentsApi.load(mga, NB_MOMENTS, null, Uri.parse(urlfreebase), "http://schemas.google.com/ReviewActivity", "me").setResultCallback(this);
}
```

Any news about this problem ?